# MYSQL select fastest time and lowest clicks for each user

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm really struggling creating a select statement that will return the record with the fastest time for each user.
If there is a tie on number if seconds, the lowest 'clicks' should be selected.

If I have the following records in my table

```
user    seconds     clicks
1       10.23       10
1       10.12       12
1       10.12       14
2       12.11       16
3       12.34       18
3       12.00       16
```

I need the lowest time and clicks for each user, so I need a query to return

```
user    seconds    clicks
1       10.12       12
2       12.11       16
3       12.00       16
```

The query I've tried is

```
select user, min(seconds), min(clicks) from mytable group by user
```

But it selects seconds 10.12 and clicks 10 for user 1 which is incorrect.
Can I do this in 1 query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation of the `greatest-n-per-group` problem that comes up frequently.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM mytable AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable AS m2 ON m.user = m2.user
  AND (m.seconds > m2.seconds OR m.seconds = m2.seconds AND m.clicks > m2.clicks)
WHERE m2.user IS NULL;
```

Explanation:

We want `m` to be the row for each user that has the lowest seconds, or if there's a tie for lowest seconds, the lowest clicks.  In other words, there should be no other row for that user with a lower seconds or a lower clicks.

Use an *exclusion join* trying to find any row with lower seconds or lower clicks.  If no such row is found, then `m` is the one with the lowest values.

---

It's still possible to result in a tie and return more than one row for a user, if there's more than one row with the least seconds *and* least clicks.  In that case, you need to resolve the tie with some other column, hopefully one that is unique.

Example:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM mytable AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable AS m2 ON m.user = m2.user
  AND (m.seconds > m2.seconds OR m.seconds = m2.seconds AND (m.clicks > m2.clicks
  OR m.clicks = m2.clicks AND m.id > m2.id))
WHERE m2.user IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inner join with self as below:

```
 select a.user, a.seconds, a.clicks 
 from mytable a JOIN
      (SELECT user, min(seconds) as MIN_SECONDS
       FROM mytable 
       GROUP BY USER) AS b
 ON a.user = b.user AND a.seconds = b.MIN_SECONDS;
```

Comment: Thanks Yogendra, but that query selects 0 rows :(

Comment: This solution with HAVING cannot work.  The value of `seconds` is taken from an arbitrary row in the group, not the row with the least seconds.  So the expression in the HAVING clause is ambiguous and returns undefined results.  HAVING is for excluding whole groups, not rows.

Comment: @BillKarwin: I updated the answer with self join query. Hope that works.

Comment: It works to find the row with the lowest `seconds` per user, but it does not satisfy the OP's other requirement to find the row with the lowest `clicks` in case of a tie.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT c.userid, c.seconds, min(c.clicks) FROM clicks as c
INNER JOIN (select userid, min(seconds) as s from clicks group by userid) AS sq 
ON (c.userid=sq.userid AND c.seconds=sq.s) group by c.userid;
```

but without any join it can't be done.

You may have to change names of columns and table.